# Removing all comments from an .r file?

Tags: r

Is there an r code I can use that will remove all of the comments from an .r file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `tidy.source()` in the formatR package, option `keep.comment = FALSE`

And an example.... copy and paste the following (including the comment).  Tidy source defaults to reading the clipboard for the code.

```
# This is a useless comment
for(i in 1:5){
  print(i)
}
```

and then

```
> library(formatR)
> tidy.source(keep.comment = FALSE)
for (i in 1:5) {
    print(i)
}
```